# What portion of the carbon credit market goes to reforestation/forest conservation projects?

Tags: carbon-sequestration, forestry, carbon-offsetting

In my understanding the supply side of the carbon credit market involves a wide range of different methods to sequester or otherwise prevent carbon from entering the atmosphere (renewable energy, fuel change etc.).  Approximately what percentage of these credits in the market represent by reforestation/conservation projects?  Combined compliance and voluntary credit markets would be ideal!

I expected this to be a relatively easy metric to find but have not been able to turn anything up in a few hours of searching.  Hoping it is an institutional knowledge type thing, thanks!